# Why is my db not connecting?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am newbie to vb.net and i am trying to connect with a sql server.

my connection string here is:

```
 <add name="ConString" connectionString="Data Source=LV-SC294\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=master;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=1111;Password=111111" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Here is my DBConnection file where i connect to the server,

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Configuration.Provider
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Data.Odbc

Namespace CATTool
Public Class DBConnection
    Protected con As OdbcConnection
    Dim b As Boolean
    Protected rs As Object

    Public Function Open(Optional ByVal connection As String = "ConString") As Boolean
        con = New OdbcConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConString").ConnectionString)
        Try
            b = True
            If (con.State.ToString <> "open") Then
                con.Open()
            End If
            Return b

        Catch ex As Exception
            Return False
        End Try
    End Function
```

and finally here is where i call my DbConnection.. Here i am trying to set up the connection with the server and also execute the query to fetch rows. How ever the connection is not established.It keeps throwing the message "Connection didn't establish"

```
 Imports System.Data
 Imports System.Data.SqlClient
 Imports System.Web.Services
 Imports CAT_Tool.CATTool
 Imports Newtonsoft.Json
 Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Linq

 Namespace CAT_Tool


Public Class SummaryController

    Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller

    '
    ' GET: /Summary
    Protected DB As DBConnection = New DBConnection()
    Private Property Val As Object
    Function Index() As ActionResult
        Return View()
    End Function
    Function Summary() As ActionResult
        Return View()
    End Function
    <WebMethod()> _
    Public Function Get_Territory()
        MsgBox("Filling Territory")
        Dim Query As String = "select distinct Territory from     dbo.CWS_WEBTOOL_USG"
        Dim dbcon As Boolean = DB.Open()
        If (dbcon = True) Then
            MsgBox("Connection Established")
            Val = DB.selectdata(Query)
            DB.Close()
            Dim serializer As New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()
            Dim rows As New List(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object))()
            Dim row As Dictionary(Of String, Object)
            For Each dr As DataRow In Val.Rows
                row = New Dictionary(Of String, Object)()
                For Each col As DataColumn In Val.Columns
                    row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr(col))
                Next
                rows.Add(row)
            Next
            MsgBox("Returning values")
            MsgBox(rows)
            Return serializer.Serialize(rows)

        Else
            MsgBox("Connection Did'nt Establish")
            Return Content(dbcon.ToString)
        End If
        Return View()
    End Function
```

My sql server details are as follows:

ServerName = LV-SC294\SQLEXPRESS
Authentication : SQLServer Authentication

Comment: If using SQL Server, have you tried using a SQLClientConnection instead of Odbc?

Comment: In your connection string you appear to be connecting to the Master database, presumably you have your own database on the server to which you should be connecting and that's the one whose name should appear in the catalog entry of the connection string.  That might not solve your issue but it is one obvious error.

Comment: Also use the built in constants to check if connection is open If con.State <> ConnectionState.Open Then
con.Open()
                End If

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @AllanS.Hansen that it is best to use `System.Data.SqlClient` to access SQL Server from managed code.  Your connection string is a proper SqlClient connection string, although one usually specifies an application database rather than the master system database.

If you want to use ODBC (e.g. same code supporting different DBMS systems), you'll need to change the connection string and provider in the config file.  For example, using the latest [SQL Server ODBC Driver](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj730314%28v=sql.110%29.aspx):

```
<add name="ConString" connectionString="Driver={ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server},Server=LV-SC294\SQLEXPRESS;Database=YourDatabase;UID=1111;PWD=111111" providerName="System.Data.Odbc"/>
```